# Find and delete a name from a sheet that is specified in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've found this script that does everything what I want, besides deleting the actual name. I have a sheet where I enter a name in cell G2 on sheet "-Dossier", after that I want to find this name in the "ZZZ - Medewerkers" sheet and when the script finds the name in that sheet I want to delete the name from that sheet. The name on the "ZZZ - Medewerkers" sheet is always in Column A.

The script that I am using now is able to find the row where the name is specified, but I have not figured out on how to actually delete the name from the sheet. Could anyone help me out?

```
function rowOfEmployee(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('ZZZ - Medewerkers');
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("-Dossier");
  var data = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var employeeName = sh1.getRange("G2").getValue();
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == employeeName){ //[0] because column A
      Logger.log((i+1))
      return i+1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
function rowOfEmployee(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("-Dossier");
  var employeeName = sh1.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('ZZZ - Medewerkers');
  sh2.createTextFinder(employeeName).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith('');
}
```